# Logic level converter not working?

Tags: arduino-uno, voltage-level, electronics, voltage

I'm trying to connect a 3.3v depth sensor to an Arduino uno. The logic level converter does not seem to send any current over (the sensor does not work and the voltmeter reads nothing). I tested the depth sensor separately, so I know it works, meaning it must be the converter. Why wouldn't it be working?

I've tried two logic level converters so far, but neither seems to work. This is basically how I connected it:

[image: wires]

Here's the LLC:
[image]

Did I mess something up soldering it or by plugging it in wrong earlier?

Comment: Try again with the photo. That could be anything. Put the gadget down on a table and hold the camera steady.

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE.  Be sure to take the tour:   https://arduino.stackexchange.com/Tour

Answer (score 6):

Based on your schematic, you need to provide a 3.3v power source to the 3.3v side of the logic level converter. You can use the 3.3v pin on the Arduino.

Also, it's really hard to evaluate your soldering with such a shaky picture. Just make sure none of the pins are connected. A visual inspection usually will do, but if you want to be sure, use your multimeter's continuity function. Test all adjacent pins to confirm they are not bridged.

Comment: Agreed. The logic-level converter doesn't manufacture 3.3V - you need to supply it.